# display delay of update with threading and swing

Tags: java, multithreading, swing

I have a thread updating my swing interface each time launched.Even though i worked with the `invokeLater()` method of `SwingUtilities` class i still have this delay.

This the run of my thread code:

```
public void run() {
    final int timeout=2000;
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                if (InetAddress.getByName(host).isReachable(timeout)){
                    ServerFrame.listModel.addElement(InetAddress.getByName(host).getHostName() + '\n');
                }
            } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });

    try {
        Thread.sleep(10);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Ant this is how i call it

```
for (int i =63;i<66 ;i++) {
    ping p = new ping("192.168.1."+i);
    p.start();
}
```

Comment: Take a read through [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/), in particular take a look at [`SwingWorker`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html), it's designed for just this purpose...

Answer (score 3):

It looks like your code is defeating its purpose.: from your thread you are submitting code to the main GUI thread which does the network call and is subject to waiting.

You should obtain the result from the network call within your thread code and only then use `invokLater` to populate the GUI with the result.